# McCormick Envelopes with more then 2 variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve a bilinear optimization problem by *linearizing* the problem using the [McCormick Envelope](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes) method.

It's quite a simple method when you are only using the product of two variables, say:

$w$ = $x*y$.

Refer to the link above for the actual process.

My question is, how would you create your optimization constraints if you want $w = x*y*a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to simply apply it recursively, i.e, introduce a new variable $z$, and apply the envelopes on $w = xz$ and $z = ya$.